# How i can add new fancybox-style (theme) for display uploaded image in WYSIWYG / CKEditor with Media module?

Tags: wysiwyg, media

When I upload new image with Media Browser (WYSIWYG + CKEditor + Media), I see themes: original, small, large... How i can add my own template to this list for fancybox?

```
<a href="full.jpg"><img src="preview.jpg" /></a>
```

Maybe already have a module for this theme?

Answer (score 0):

Go to configuration, media, image,styles, add style, or directly

```
http://example.com/admin/config/media/image-styles/add
```

And add a custom image style.